# How can i count row elements using cursor in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im working with huge data. So, i decided to use cursor intead of get. But i can't a way to do this with laravel. I'm using laravel 5.6. Thanks in advance

This is the documentation of the object returned 
[PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_NUM` style to get an array which you can count using `count()`.

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$count = count($result);
```

Comment: Im using laravel, it returns a generator. And i still cant count it with that method. I already read the documentation.